# QGIS GeoSearch Plugin Issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps

We are trying to use the QGIS GeoSearch plugin and intermittently receive issues with it. We know what the cause is and we wondered whether anyone else experienced this issue and had a solution?

We understand that the GeoSearch plugin uses ‘maps.googleapis.com’ which we have allowed through our firewall, however it appears that Google Safe Search can sometimes refuse our connection when performing a post code search with the GeoSearch plugin. We have tried to find the ip address range which Google use in order for this range to be allowed on our firewall, which temporarily fixes the issue but when Google add another ip range, the plugin fails to work. We then have to add the new range to our firewall rules in order to get it temporaliy working again. The Safe search domain is 1e100.net. We cannot add wildcard domains to the firewall outgoing http traffic but we can add IP ranges.